PNPM Workspaces - how to activate some "hot reload" when changing packages?
I'm facing a bit of a challenge to configure a monorepo with pnpm workspaces.
Saying I have the following structure:
apps
  - application1
  - application2
packages
  - @my-project/package1
  - @my-project/package2
  - @my-project/package3

My pnpm workspace configuration is fairly simple:
# pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'apps/**/*'
  - 'packages/**/*'

How do I reference packages into apps?
package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-project/package1": "workspace:*",
    "@my-project/package2": "workspace:*",
    "@my-project/package3": "workspace:*",
  } 
}

So far, so good. All my applcations run and the dependencies work exactly as expected. However, I have a bit of a problem.
One of my applications is a NestJS backend service. It references some of those libraries. Whenever I change something on the NestJS application itself, the "hot reload" functionality works seamsly. Whenever I change anything on any of the referenced packages, I need to stop my NestJS service, re-install its dependencies and start the application again in order to make it seeing my latest changes.
Do you guys know if there is a way to configure the NestJS application/Typescript or something to, whenever something is changed on the packages, they are built and its dist is already set to the apps I'm running?
Thank y'all!

Regarding your 'hot-reload' issue, i had the same problem for more than two days.
After rummaging around in the nestjs and webpack docs (not enough I guess), I'd had enough and put in place a pretty nasty but working solution.
Since I couldn't find a way to configure the hot-reload, I found a way to “force” it.
Where my architecture might differ from yours is that I use npm workspaces instead of pnpm.
Below is the structure of my project:
workspace/
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── scripts/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── force-hmr.ts   <-----
│   └── dist
├── apps/
│   └── nest-backend/
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       ├── dist
│       ├── __hmr__.ts   <-----
│       └── ...
└── shared/
    └── shared-lib/
        ├── package.json
        ├── src
        └── dist

My nest application imports the 'shared-lib' package.
The idea is to make the nest application believe that local modifications have been made.
To do this, modify a dummy ts file at the root of the application (here, __hmr__.ts). Each time this file is modified, the application will restart.
What's left to do is simply track your dependency files.
As soon as a modification has been detected, you modify the __hmr__.ts file again.
Here's the script force-hmr.ts I use. It uses the devDependency chokidar to track file modifications:
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs";

import chokidar from "chokidar";

const DIR_TO_WATCH = path.join(__dirname, "../..", "shared/*/src/**/*.ts");

const FILE_TO_TOUCH = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "../..",
  "apps/nest-backend/__hmr__.ts"
);

console.log(`Tracking changes on path: ${DIR_TO_WATCH}`);
const watcher = chokidar.watch(DIR_TO_WATCH, {
  persistent: true,
});

watcher.on("all", () => {
  fs.writeFileSync(FILE_TO_TOUCH, "//" + Date.now().toString());
});


Just run it concurrently with your nest dev server.
In my case (npm workspaces), nestjs restarts and takes into account the latest changes made in my libs.
I'm not proud of this solution, but for the moment it's the only one I've found that lets me develop comfortably.
If anyone has a cleaner solution, I'd love to hear about it.
I hope this solution works for you.

Nice one! Let me try it and ill get back to you with some feedback :)
